# Firebase Dynamic Links ITC Analytics Settings

Tags: firebase, app-store-connect, firebase-dynamic-links, itunesconnect-analytics

When building a Dynamic Link with the Firebase Dynamic Links API, one of the property groupings is [`ITunesConnectAnalyticsParameters`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/dynamic-links/i-tunes-connect-analytics-parameters).  It lists the following settings:

- AffiliateToken: The affiliate token used to create affiliate-coded links.
- CampaignToken: The campaign token that developers can add to any link in order to track sales from a specific marketing campaign.
- ProviderToken: The provider token that enables analytics for Dynamic Links from within iTunes Connect.

What are these values and how do I know what to set them to?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Summary

- Affiliate Token: This is likely unnecessary if you are building one of these links with the Firebase Dynamic Links API, unless you intend to give monetary credit for the link to another entity.  I did not find how to get this value for any given entity.
- Campaign Token: This can be any value, and it will show up in your iTunes Connect dashboard attached to any analytics events that occur with this link.
- Provider Token: Should be the unique Provider ID available in App Analytics in the iTunes Connect dashboard.  Visit `iTunes Connect` > `App Analytics` > `[Your App]` > `Sources` > `Campaigns` > `Generate a Campaign Link` to find yours.

## Provider ID:

> This parameter is for app developers only. Apple's developer portal, iTunes Connect, includes analytics that help developers track additional data related to their apps. Each developer has a unique provider token that can be found in the App Analytics section of iTunes Connect. When added to an iTunes URL, a provider token enables analytics for those links from within iTunes Connect.

[(Source)](https://www.macstories.net/tutorials/a-comprehensive-guide-to-the-itunes-affiliate-program/)

> App developers were assigned provider IDs as part of the roll out of iTunes Connect Analytics. Sign into iTunes Connect with your Apple developer credentials and select the App Analytics section of iTunes Connect. Select one of your apps and then the "Top Campaigns" tab. Finally, select "Generate a Campaign Link." Your provider ID should be listed right next to your app's Apple ID. Searchr will add your provider ID to links it generates, which will allow you to track clicks on links for apps you own via iTunes Connect Analytics.

[(Source)](https://searchr.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/775704-i-m-an-app-developer-how-do-i-find-my-provider-id)

> *[In reference to Fastlane]*
> When you have multiple accounts, you need to collect 3 pieces of information.
>
> - team_id which is the 10-character string
> - itc_team_id which is the numeric itunes connect team id
> - itc_provider_id which in newer accounts matches team_id, but for older accounts is a slug for the business name. (e.g. AwesomeOrgLLC)
>
> [Examples]
>
> - app_team_id = 'AB83BKF89B'
> - itc_team_id = '1384242'
> - itc_provider_id = 'AwesomeOrgLLC'

[(Source)](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/10796#issuecomment-352952685)

> *[Also in reference to Fastlane]*
> The ITC provider ID is sometimes required in order to upload binaries to Apple when you have multiple accounts...the provider ID is distinct from the developer portal team ID and the iTunes Connect team ID.

[(Source)](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/10796#issuecomment-353198382)

## Affiliate Token:

> You need an affiliate token to get credit in the iTunes affiliate program...

[(Source)](https://searchr.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/775695-do-i-need-an-affiliate-token-and-a-campaign-token)

> To create affiliate-coded links simply add to the end of any iTunes, App Store, iBooks, or Mac App Store URL the parameter “at” and your Affiliate Token.
>
> This is a properly coded affiliate link for the account with Affiliate Token “12345”: https://itunes.apple.com/sg/artist/bruno-mars/id278873078?at=12345

[(Source)](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/basic_affiliate_link_guidelines_for_the_phg_network/)

> This is the money parameter. If you do not add your affiliate token to a link somewhere after the ?, your link will take people to the intended media, but you won’t earn a commission. Affiliate tokens are composed of two parts. The first part is a series of 1s and 0s that never start with a 0. The second part is a series of alphanumeric characters of varying length that is separated from the first part of the token by a lower case letter “L.” It’s important to recognize that this separator is a lowercase letter “L” because it can be easy to mistake it for a capital letter "I," a number 1, or a pipe “|” character.
>
> The affiliate token is preceded by at= in the full URL. In the Arctic Monkeys example, the affiliate token is 11lbfL and is preceded by &at= because it is not the first parameter in the link.

[(Source)](https://www.macstories.net/tutorials/a-comprehensive-guide-to-the-itunes-affiliate-program/)

## Campaign Token:

> You do not need to include a campaign token to get iTunes affiliate program credit, but they are a handy way to track links used in different places. For instance, you might have one campaign token for your blog and another for a Twitter account so you can see how much affiliate traffic each generates.

[(Source)](https://www.macstories.net/tutorials/a-comprehensive-guide-to-the-itunes-affiliate-program/)

> Campaign Token
>
> The ‘ct’ value is campaign text that you can optionally add to any link in order to track sales from a specific marketing campaign. By using a campaign value, you will see in the reporting dashboard all clicks and sales related to that specific campaign.
>
> For example, the link below has added a campaign tracking parameter for a newsletter link. You can name the campaigns anything you choose, but the ‘ct’ value may not be longer than 40 characters, as noted in the examples from the table above.
>
> (Example:) https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/fame-monster-deluxe-version/id902143901?mt=1&at=123456&app=itunes&ct=newsletter1

[(Source)](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/basic_affiliate_link_guidelines_for_the_phg_network/)

Comment: I "like" that somebody downvoted this without any explanation.  Do I have something wrong?